# What does 'fungus-growing' mean?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, compound-adjectives, participial-phrases, nonfinite-clause-complementation, attributive-adjectives

> Renowned Swiss entomologist Martin Luscher described the mounds of
>   this fungus-growing species as being as much as 16 feet tall, 16 feet
>   in diameter at their base, and with a cement-like wall of soil mixed
>   with termite saliva that is from 16 to 23 inches thick.

Does the above mean species that feed on fungus?

Can I use phrases like "grass-growing", "meat-growing", etc.?

Comment: The first question may be better asked on Biology SE

Comment: Reads to me like the "species" (whatever it is) grows fungus. Hence the use of the hyphenated "fungus-growing".  Please provide examples of where you'd like to use "meat-growing", etc.

Comment: He's referring to a species of termite that brings in material for the fungus to grow on. These termites actively cultivate this fungus and will die without it.  They don't actually eat the fungus (although people do), the fungus helps to break down the cellulose which the termites feed on.

Answer (score 3):

An *entomologist* is an insect expert. The sentence seems to refer to a species of termite that cultivates a fungus within its mounds to provide food for the colony. That is, they 'grow fungi' - nothing to do with growing up.

We sometimes speak of a district that specialises in a particular crop as a *wheat-growing area*, or a *vine-growing district*. We wouldn't use it of grass (too universal) or of meat (you *raise* animals, not grow them).

Comment: One might say "grass-growing region" about places suited to or specialising in growing marijuana.

Comment: It seems like every day now we have recurring questions from people trying to learn English but who do not understand that the syntactic structure behind *this **OBJECT-VERBing** NOUN* is that this is merely an attributive version of *this NOUN that VERBs OBJECTs". It’s as though all the [ell.se] were reading the same chapter in the same workbook, some textbook where this isn't explained to them properly and then they wind up coming here instead of to [ell.se] which is made for them.